# ambiguous column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, and I want to connect the tables by `CustomerID` (`CustomerID` is same for two tables). So I used my query like:

```
SELECT
   Cus.CustomerID
FROM
   Customers AS Cus
JOIN
   Payments AS Pay ON Cus.CustomerID = Pay.CustomerID
WHERE
  CustomerID = 2
```

And it shows an error:

> 'CustomerID' in where clause is ambiguous

How can I resolve ambiguous column name error in a way that does not add the table name before `CustomerID`?

Comment: Then add the prefix of the table on the `WHERE`: `WHERE Cus.CustomerID = 2` for example

Comment: What do you mean " that does not add the table name before CustomerID"?

Comment: Do some **research** on the **Error Message** before asking a question. This is Pretty basic stuff!!

Comment: Alias the column so names are no longer ambiguous: `FROM (select CustomerId as CustId from Customers) as Cus`

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it doesn't know which `CustomerID` to use in your `where` clause `CustomerID = 2`, you should specify which to use:

```
SELECT
   Cus.CustomerID
FROM
   Customers AS Cus
JOIN
   Payments AS Pay
ON
   Cus.CustomerID = Pay.CustomerID
WHERE
  Cus.CustomerID = 2
```

It doesn't matter if you use `Cus.CustomerID` or `Pay.CustomerID` since they will always be the same in your current statement (since you equal them in your `join`).

Answer (score 3):

The ambigious part is here:

```
WHERE
  CustomerID = 2
```

Both tables have this column you need to be explict either:

```
Cus.CustomerID
```

or

```
Pay.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 3):

> [I]n a way that does not add the table name before CustomerID

You can use a sub-query.

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM
(
  SELECT
     Cus.CustomerID
  FROM
     Customers AS Cus
  JOIN
     Payments AS Pay
  ON
     Cus.CustomerID = Pay.CustomerID
) query
WHERE CustomerID = 2
```

Is this a good way? No. This may force the query plan to use a scan instead of a seek if CustomerID is an indexed field (which it should be since this is being joined on).

Comment: `Is this a good way? No` Then *Why*?

Comment: To answer the original question. Yes, there was a way to specify the where condition without using the table name. I thought that I gave a reason why this wouldn't be a good method: because of the possible query plan issue.

Comment: @Martin Soles  Thank you